# How to read a custom file format .fid

Tags: matlab, file, format

I have files with extension .fid

I want to read the data off of the file with matlab preferably. Is there anyway to do this with a custom file format like this?

If not, is there any other way I can transform this custom file format into something else? such as .csv?

Comment: Have you tried with 'textscan'?

Comment: What else do you know about the file? What has written it?

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with this file type, but if it's human-readable, if you can open it in text editor and see the data, then there shouldn't be a problem. You can [`textscan`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) to import data, if it's properly formatted, or [`fileread`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileread.html) to import the entire file as string. You can even use `uiimport` to import data in interactive mode. Check MATLAB documentation for [Data import and export](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/data-import-and-export.html)